# set only a part from a value .setValues

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple code picking some informations from some sheets to an other
the result is this :
[image]

and I would like to clean it a bit, if a box in the column M is empty, I would like L and N to be empty too.
so I wrote this code :

```
//clean the empty value
  var d2cleanervalues = PLsheet.getRange(2,13,COsheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  
  for( let i=0; i<d2cleanervalues.length; i++ ) {
  if( d2cleanervalues[i][0] === "" ) d2cleanervalues[i][0] = "whou";
  PLsheet.getRange(2,12, d2cleanervalues.length, 1 ).setValues(d2cleanervalues);
  PLsheet.getRange(2,14, d2cleanervalues.length, 1 ).setValues(d2cleanervalues);
  }
```

but as you can see on the code, it copy all the content from column M to column L and N

I would like it only to copy the boxes who are empty !
So how can I set the values only from the empty boxes ?
not doing this :
[image]

but doing this :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this modification of your code to get the desired output:

```
var d2cleanervalues = PLsheet.getRange(2, 13, PLsheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  for (let i = 0; i < d2cleanervalues.length; i++) {
    if (d2cleanervalues[i][0] === "") {
      PLsheet.getRange(2 + i, 12, 1, 1).setValue(d2cleanervalues[i][0]);
      PLsheet.getRange(2 + i, 14, 1, 1).setValue(d2cleanervalues[i][0]);
    }
  }
```

Each iteration would clean only the cell in Column `L` and `N` and only if the original value `M` is empty:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it.  Since column L to N contain only values, get the values in the 3 columns.  Next using `Array.forEach()` clean each row.  Lastly put the values back.

Avoid using `getValue()/setValue()` and `getValues()/setValues()` in loops as much as possible.  See [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).

You are getting values from `PLSheet` but `COSheet.getLastRow()`, are you sure they are the same length.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let PLsheet = spread.getSheetByName("PLsheet");
    //clean the empty value  get columns L:N
    let range = PLsheet.getRange(2,12,PLsheet.getLastRow()-1,3);
    let d2cleanervalues = range.getValues();

    d2cleanervalues.forEach( row => {
        if( row[1] === "" ) {
          row[0] = "";
          row[2] = "";
        }
      }
    );

    range.setValues(d2cleanervalues);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

References

- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)